# Is it possible to print out debugging logs while task is running in ansible?

Tags: bash, ansible

If I'm not mistaken, we can print out debug (stdout/stderr) logs of bash after task is done in Ansible.

**hello-world.sh**

```
ping -c 5 www.google.com
```

**my-playbook.yml**

```
tasks:
  - block:
      - name: Print out hello world
        command: "./hello-world.sh"
        register: result
      - debug: var=result.stdout_lines
  - name: Print script execution result
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: result
      verbosity: 4
```

Regarding above, ping results will be printed out after 5 times reach. That's why I'm curious to know how to print out each **ping result while task is running** in Ansible instead of task completed.

Comment: Sadly, as far as I know there is no way to do what you want in ansible, since it is a "run this script and tell me what happened" and not "be a copy of expect driving an ssh connection"

Answer (score 2):

According [Introduction to modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/modules_intro.html) and [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible executes each module, usually on the remote managed node, and collects return values.*

and

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable ...*

such live output is not implemented.

Regarding your question

> *How to print out each ping result while task is running in Ansible instead?*

there is an option for [Debugging modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html)

> *To see what is actually happening in the module*

but that is probably not you were looking for in your use case.

---

An other option might be

- either ping just once, register the result, print the result, repeat this five times
- use [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)
- or [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met)