# Get logs while developing an Ansible Collection

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

I'm wondering when developing an Ansible Collection, is it possible to get arbitrary logs written to a log file/console?

This being a random `print()` statement to help debugging, or is the only way just to concatenate your final return message?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**

> *Is it possible to get arbitrary logs written to a log file/console?*

**Answer:**

Your question for me looks similar to [Is it possible to print out debugging logs while task is running in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71813720/6771046).

According the answer there citing from documentation

> *Ansible executes each module, usually on the remote managed node, and collects return values. ...*
> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable ...*

so such live output is not implemented. There is an option for [Debugging modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html) during development

> *To see what is actually happening in the module*

but that might not fit all of your cases.

---

**Question:**

> *This being a random `print()` statement to help debugging*

**Answer:**

According the **Developer Guide » Debugging modules » [Simple debugging](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html#simple-debugging)**

> *Since `print()` statements do not work inside modules, raising an exception is a good approach if you just want to see some specific data. Put `raise Exception(some_value)` somewhere in the module and run it normally. Ansible will handle this exception, pass the message back to the control node, and display it.*