# How can I get the output of an Ansible play as it is being run?

Tags: ansible

By default a
Ansible will cache all the output (`stdout` and `stderr`) and then attempts to present it in a readable manner.

Is this something that can be enabled / disabled?

Ansible attempts to present everything in a JSON format and it sometimes ends up being almost unreadable as if the program attempts to output a JSON too it gets compacted.

Can I get the output as it is being given by the program to Ansible rather than wait for the task to finish?

Comment: No, it is not meant for that. You do have a more readable output in YAML format though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009505/ansible-stdout-formatting

Comment: Does [Is it possible to print out debugging logs while task is running in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71813720/6771046) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your post contains two questions, one about formatting output and the other about realtime or streaming logs, I like to focus on the main one.

---

> *Is this something that can be enabled / disabled?*

Not directly.

> *Can I get the output as it is being given by the program to Ansible rather than wait for the task to finish?*

It depends. According [Introduction to modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/modules_intro.html) and [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible executes each module, usually on the remote managed node, and collects return values.*

and

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable ...*

therefore such live output is not implemented. See also [How to display realtime `shell` `stdout`](https://serverfault.com/a/972664/448950)?

> *"Real time" or "streaming" output has not been merged to Ansible yet. The [original issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3887) was closed in 2014 as not feasible. A [more recent proposal](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/92) has no major updates since February 2018.*

But there is a way if [Debugging Custom Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448411/6771046) or as workaround [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773566/6771046)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: Run `shell` command with `async` module to capture its output on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75295004/)