# Run a command with ansible, wait for some output then terminate command

Tags: ansible

Is there any way to use Ansible to run a command on a remote host (which blocks, forever), wait for some specific output, then terminate the command. I am thinking there isn't in "native" ansible because I don't think even running tasks async can inspect output until the task returns. Although I'm wondering if I can write a module to do this.

Comment: Does [How can I get the output of an Ansible play as it is being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76341703/6771046) answer your question?

Comment: "_I am thinking there isn't in "native" Ansible ..._", as far as I interpret such cases, the native Ansible way is to use Distributed Computing Paradigms, which it makes then somehow easy and quite simple.

Comment: Could you therefore provide more information regarding your Use Case? What command(s) you are running? What kind of output or which content do you wait or looking for? Maybe there are already implementations for your case which one could point you to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use `ansible.builtin.expect`:

```
---
- name: Show expect to kill process
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: Test expect
    ansible.builtin.expect:
      command: /home/jack/Ansible/General/Playbooks/run_forever.sh
      timeout: -1
      responses:
        "Time to die":
        - "\x03"
...
```

To test that,I have this:

```
$ cat /home/jack/Ansible/General/Playbooks/run_forever.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    sleep 10
    echo "Time to die"
done
```

The result is:

$ ansible-playbook -i local_inventory/ Playbooks/expect.yml

```
PLAY [Show expect to kill process] ****************************************************************************************

TASK [Test expect] ********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/home/jack/Ansible/General/Playbooks/run_forever.sh", "delta": "0:00:10.154058", "end": "2023-10-20 09:53:35.686094", "msg": "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null, "start": "2023-10-20 09:53:25.532036", "stdout": "Time to die", "stdout_lines": ["Time to die"]}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Now, you may want to put in a `failed_when` clause so that you do not actually fail there, but that's on you.